# IIS 6 does not pick up the default document shows "Directory Listing Denied"

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net 3.5 web site i have default.html page defined as first default document in iis 6 web site configuration window. I have URL rewriting module written and when the request for default.htm comes its pointed to default.aspx page. When i hit www.mysite.com/defaut.htm it correctly displays default.aspx page (with url rewritten) but when i hit just www.mysite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is IIS 6 checks whether the requested document exists for default documents list that has been entered in website setup unlike for non default documents.Putting a dummy default.htm fixed the issue.So if URL rewriting is used should make sure to use them for only non default documents only otherwise it will not work for default documents if the url is physically not exists or should create a dummy file that match the virtual URL.